# Create a function that will change the list passed in with a parameter of name at a given index

Tags: python, list

I want to create a function that will change the list passed in with a parameter of name at a given index. For example:

```
mylist = ['Mike', 'Terry', 'Kate', 'Brian']
```

I want to replace Terry at index[1] with Matt but I have to use function like this:

```
def changeName(newList, name, index):
```

so the newList output should be:

```
newList = ['Mike', 'Matt', 'Kate', 'Brian']
```

Much appreciated.

I tried this but it does't satisfy the requirement.

```
mylist = ['Mike', 'Terry', 'Kate', 'Brian']
def changeName(aList):
    aList[1] = 'Matt'
changeName(mylist)
print(mylist)
```

Comment: we are not your employee or something that do your work. In addition this sounds like a homework. We are here to help you in case you have a problem and struggle. But to have a problem you first have to try it yourself. So show some effort and try to solve the problem yourself and in case you still need help show us what you tried and we may help you then.

Comment: hmm I'm not angry at all. You should maybe read [ask] and see [tour] to see how to ask good questions. Maybe this is also good for you: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: Updated as you guided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You nearly had it.

```
def changeName(newList, name, index):
    newList[index] = name

changeName(mylist,"Matt",1)
```

Basically if a function have one, two or a lot of parameters doesn't make a difference at all. There are some special cases you can do (like an unlimited number of parameter, default values and so on, but this is not that important for now).

In addition don't name your variable `list` this is a built-in function and it may cause trouble in the future if you use that as your variable name. That's why I called it `mylist`.

Comment: Thank Boendal. I am self-learning python. do you know any good book for beginner like me as I don't have any programming experience.

Comment: @MikeB not really I also self-learned it but I had already programming experience in other languages (know one, know it all more or less). I think with practice you will improve and yeah Google some guide/book. For the start any will do more or less (but look that you take a new one and espeically Python 3, Python 2 is down)

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, if you're using / simulating the functional style, you may wish to create and return an entirely new list with the required changes made to it.

```
def changeName(oldlist, name, index):
    newlist = list(oldlist) #copy the old list
    newlist[index] = name   #change item at index
    return newlist

#which you then use like this:
edited = changeName(mylist,"Matt",1)
```

Comment: Hi hbregalad, Yeah, I am moving to Return, this would be useful. Thank you.